# Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock Android App

Tags: android

I have been working on this app today and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code.

When I check, there is no syntax errors. But when I attempt to run it and debug it, it says

`"Source not found" on "ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2106`

It gives me the option to choose another path but the only one available is the default setting. Did I code this wrong? What can I do to fix this?

This is the logcat:

```
12-20 22:12:29.722: I/System.out(1518): debugger has settled (1479) 
12-20 22:12:30.172: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
12-20 22:12:30.222: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

here is my source file:

```
package com.example.rockpaperscissorlizardspock;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class rockpaperscissorlizardspock extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView resultText;
    private Button play, reset;
    private ImageButton scissors, paper, rock, lizard, spock;
    private int paperimg, paper_pressedimg, scissorsimg, scissors_pressedimg,     rockimg, rock_pressedimg, lizardimg, lizard_pressedimg, spockimg, spock_pressedimg;
        private ImageView compSciss, compPaper, compRock, compLiz, compSpock;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int compChoice = 0;
    String pChoice ="";
    String cChoice = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialize();
    }

    /** initialize all of the components*/
     private void Initialize()
    {
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        lizard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        spock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        scissors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        paper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        rock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        compSciss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerScissors);
        compPaper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerPaper);
        compRock = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerRock);
        spockimg = R.raw.spock;
        spock_pressedimg = R.raw.spock_pressed;
        lizardimg = R.raw.lizard;
        lizard_pressedimg = R.raw.lizard_pressed;
        paperimg = R.raw.paper;
        paper_pressedimg = R.raw.paper_pressed;
        scissorsimg = R.raw.scissors;
        scissors_pressedimg = R.raw.scissors_pressed;
        rockimg = R.raw.rock1;
        rock_pressedimg = R.raw.rock1_pressed;

        /**set the button Listeners*/
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                play();
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);

                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                compPaper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                compRock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                compSciss.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                compLiz.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                compSpock.setImageResource    (spockimg);               
                pChoice = "";
                cChoice = "";
                play.setEnabled(false);
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                scissors.setEnabled(true);
                paper.setEnabled(true);
                rock.setEnabled(true);
                lizard.setEnabled(true);
                spock.setEnabled(true);
                resultText.setText("");
            }
        });

        /*
         * Declaring what happens when specific choices are made.
         */

        scissors.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){    
                     scissors.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
                    paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "S";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
             }
         });

         paper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                    paper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
                    scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "P";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        rock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                rock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                pChoice = "R";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        lizard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                 lizard.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
                 spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                 scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                 paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                 pChoice = "L";
                 play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        spock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                spock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                pChoice = "SP";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

    }

    /**The method that chooses the computer's move and compares
     *  to the player's move.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        compChoice = rand.nextInt(5);

        if(compChoice == 0)
        {
            cChoice = "R";
            compRock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 1){
            cChoice = "P";
            compPaper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
        }       
         else if(compChoice == 2)
        {
            cChoice = "S";
            compSciss.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 3)
           {
            cChoice = "L";
             compLiz.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 4)
       { 
       cChoice = "SP";
       compSpock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
       }

    check();
}

/**
 * Compares the Computer's and the Player's moves.
 */
public void check()
{
    if(pChoice == "R") //Rock
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "P") //Paper
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "S") //Scissors
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "L") //Lizard
    {
      if(cChoice == "R")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "L")
        resultText.setText("Draw");

      else if(cChoice == "SP")
        resultText.setText("You Win");

      else if(cChoice == "S")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "P")
        resultText.setText("You Win");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "SP") //Spock
    {
        if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

    }

    gameOver();
}


/**
 * Runs at the end of each round. Disables all of the buttons
 * except for the reset button.
 */
public void gameOver()
{
    play.setEnabled(false);
    scissors.setEnabled(false);
    rock.setEnabled(false);
    paper.setEnabled(false);
    spock.setEnabled(false);
    lizard.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: +1 I just watched that Big Bang Theory episode an hour ago ;)

Comment: I actually started doing an app like this myself, ha, but I abandoned it for any forseeable future. :) On a more relevant note, could you post the complete logcat?

Comment: By the way, when comparing Strings, use the `.equals()` method. `==` is **not** reliable for comparing any Objects including Strings.

Comment: Please provide more details about this error, esp. a full stack trace. Additionally, this sounds like the error was caused by the debugger which is unable to show the source of the `ActivityThread` class when trying to display the actual error.

Comment: I'm trying to get the logcat but its taking a long time.

Comment: As for the equals, I tried that and it had so many syntax errors that it looked too hard and complicated for this.

Comment: This is what I get on the logcat

Comment: 12-20 22:12:29.722: I/System.out(1518): debugger has settled (1479)
12-20 22:12:30.172: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-20 22:12:30.222: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to single step into the `ActivityThread` class. The source of this class is not available in the SDK. So in short there is nothing wrong.

Comment: You simply cannot debug a class when you don't have the source. Step over the call to get back to your code.

Comment: Sorry I still dont understand. I just started on android development. can you explain further?

Comment: [2012-12-20 17:19:45 - rockPaperScissorLizardSpock] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.rockpaperscissorlizardspock/.MainActivity }
[2012-12-20 17:19:45 - rockPaperScissorLizardSpock] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: This console message just means, that the app was not again sent to the device because it did already run (and was not changed).

Comment: For the source not found: the android SDK just contains the API classes (the ones you directly use from your code). The `ActivityThread` class is deep in the system. It is only available on the device (or emulator) in binary form. Therefore you cannot debug into it.