# Developing Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock problems

Tags: android

I have been working on this app today and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code.

When I check, there is no syntax errors. But when I attempt to run it and debug it, it says

```
"Source not found" on "ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2106`
```

It gives me the option to choose another path but the only one available is the default setting. Did I code this wrong? What can I do to fix this?

This is the logcat:

```
12-20 22:12:29.722: I/System.out(1518): debugger has settled (1479) 
12-20 22:12:30.172: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
12-20 22:12:30.222: W/Trace(1518): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Heres the console error:

```
[2012-12-20 17:19:45 - rockPaperScissorLizardSpock] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.rockpaperscissorlizardspock/.MainActivity }
[2012-12-20 17:19:45 - rockPaperScissorLizardSpock] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

here is my source file:

```
package com.example.rockpaperscissorlizardspock;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class rockpaperscissorlizardspock extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView resultText;
    private Button play, reset;
    private ImageButton scissors, paper, rock, lizard, spock;
    private int paperimg, paper_pressedimg, scissorsimg, scissors_pressedimg,     rockimg, rock_pressedimg, lizardimg, lizard_pressedimg, spockimg, spock_pressedimg;
        private ImageView compSciss, compPaper, compRock, compLiz, compSpock;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int compChoice = 0;
    String pChoice ="";
    String cChoice = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialize();
    }

    /** initialize all of the components*/
     private void Initialize()
    {
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        lizard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        spock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        scissors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        paper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        rock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        compSciss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerScissors);
        compPaper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerPaper);
        compRock = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.computerRock);
        spockimg = R.raw.spock;
        spock_pressedimg = R.raw.spock_pressed;
        lizardimg = R.raw.lizard;
        lizard_pressedimg = R.raw.lizard_pressed;
        paperimg = R.raw.paper;
        paper_pressedimg = R.raw.paper_pressed;
        scissorsimg = R.raw.scissors;
        scissors_pressedimg = R.raw.scissors_pressed;
        rockimg = R.raw.rock1;
        rock_pressedimg = R.raw.rock1_pressed;

        /**set the button Listeners*/
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                play();
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);

                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                compPaper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                compRock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                compSciss.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                compLiz.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                compSpock.setImageResource    (spockimg);               
                pChoice = "";
                cChoice = "";
                play.setEnabled(false);
                reset.setEnabled(true);
                scissors.setEnabled(true);
                paper.setEnabled(true);
                rock.setEnabled(true);
                lizard.setEnabled(true);
                spock.setEnabled(true);
                resultText.setText("");
            }
        });

        /*
         * Declaring what happens when specific choices are made.
         */

        scissors.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){    
                     scissors.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
                    paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "S";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
             }
         });

         paper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                    paper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
                    scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                    spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                    rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                    lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                    pChoice = "P";
                    play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        rock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                rock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                pChoice = "R";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        lizard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                 lizard.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
                 spock.setImageResource(spockimg);
                 rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                 scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                 paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                 pChoice = "L";
                 play.setEnabled(true);
            }
         });

        spock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                spock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
                lizard.setImageResource(lizardimg);
                rock.setImageResource(rockimg);
                scissors.setImageResource(scissorsimg);
                paper.setImageResource(paperimg);
                pChoice = "SP";
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

    }

    /**The method that chooses the computer's move and compares
     *  to the player's move.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        compChoice = rand.nextInt(5);

        if(compChoice == 0)
        {
            cChoice = "R";
            compRock.setImageResource(rock_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 1){
            cChoice = "P";
            compPaper.setImageResource(paper_pressedimg);
        }       
         else if(compChoice == 2)
        {
            cChoice = "S";
            compSciss.setImageResource(scissors_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 3)
           {
            cChoice = "L";
             compLiz.setImageResource(lizard_pressedimg);
            }
        else if(compChoice == 4)
       { 
       cChoice = "SP";
       compSpock.setImageResource(spock_pressedimg);
       }

    check();
}

/**
 * Compares the Computer's and the Player's moves.
 */
public void check()
{
    if(pChoice == "R") //Rock
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "P") //Paper
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "S") //Scissors
    {
        if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");


    }

    else if(pChoice == "L") //Lizard
    {
      if(cChoice == "R")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "L")
        resultText.setText("Draw");

      else if(cChoice == "SP")
        resultText.setText("You Win");

      else if(cChoice == "S")
        resultText.setText("You Lose");

      else if(cChoice == "P")
        resultText.setText("You Win");
    }

    else if(pChoice == "SP") //Spock
    {
        if(cChoice == "SP")
            resultText.setText("Draw");

        else if(cChoice == "L")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "S")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

        else if(cChoice == "P")
            resultText.setText("You Lose");

        else if(cChoice == "R")
            resultText.setText("You Win");

    }

    gameOver();
}


/**
 * Runs at the end of each round. Disables all of the buttons
 * except for the reset button.
 */
public void gameOver()
{
    play.setEnabled(false);
    scissors.setEnabled(false);
    rock.setEnabled(false);
    paper.setEnabled(false);
    spock.setEnabled(false);
    lizard.setEnabled(false);
    reset.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: The console _"error"_ is just a _warning_...

Comment: I kinda figured. I'm new to computer science and android programming. Just looking to finish this little home project soon cause I would like to play it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981183/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-android-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add the activity to your AndroidManifest.xml. It will look something like this, and be located in the 'application' section of the manifest. You can read this page for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Here's an example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".rockpaperscissorlizardspock"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I misread things. The app launches fine?

Comment: No it doesn't. I try to run the app and before anything happens, it just sends me an error saying the application cannot open. It's really frustrating when it doesn't even give me a hint that I was on the right track

Comment: Ah! Okay. One second, and I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Actually, one sec, there is a difference

Comment: Hmmm. Then I'm not sure what would be going on... because you're not getting any actual errors in the output you show above. There must be something else showing up in logcat.

Comment: No problem. I've run into manifest issues a few times. :) I'd guess you were missing the intent filter section, or part of it. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah the "<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />" part actually stated my com.package...." It was weird.